# How to know selected file in C#

Tags: c#, hook, api-hook

I want to build a software.
This software will just get the path of currently selected file.
Suppose I click a file on my desktop.
Now I want to get the path of this file.
So whenever a new selection is made just get the path of newly selected file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You just want this on the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows Desktop window is a ListView Control like in the end (at least it was in Windows XP...) so if you need to know selected item of a ListView you basically need to get the handle of the desktop and check what has been selected.

Not sure about windows Vista and 7 bit I guess it's not too different, as David has commented, if you want this for every single explorer window could be more difficult but should still be possible, have a look here for a start:

[How do I get the window handle of the desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-do-i-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop)

Comment: actually see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222749/i-created-a-program-to-hide-desktop-icons-on-double-click-of-desktop-but-would-on there is already the C# code to find the desktop. This does not solve your exact issue but you can copy a lot of code and see how it works to detect the double click on the desktop :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class

Comment: and how could this help in detecting selected file in the desktop?

Comment: As the question is vague I was wondering if he is looking to open a file in his application. Maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use what Shaun had said about looking at OpenFileDialog.

You can also refer to this link below:

[How to use OpenFileDialog](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p9.html)

That link also teaches you how to change the title, filtering files of type and 1 or 2 others regarding OpenFileDialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: he does not need this, he wants to know on which file on the desktop or on the windows user interface the user has clicked and the file got selected.