# How to get desktop item count in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, win32gui

I'm trying to get the number of items on the desktop using win32gui in python 2.7.

The following code: `win32gui.SendMessage(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(), LVM_GETITEMCOUNT)` returns zero and I have no idea why.

I wrote `win32api.GetLastError()` afterwards and it returned zero either.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I need to use this method because the final goal is to get the positions of the icons, and it's done by a similar method. So I just wanted to make sure that I know how to use this method. Also, I think that it can give a different output than listing the content of desktop (can it?). And thirdly, my sources of how to get the positions suggested to do it this way - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop for example.

EDIT2:

Full code for getting the count (doesn't work for me):

```
import win32gui
from commctrl import LVM_GETITEMCOUNT
print win32gui.SendMessage(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(), LVM_GETITEMCOUNT)
```

Thanks again!

SOLUTION:

```
import ctypes
from commctrl import LVM_GETITEMCOUNT
import pywintypes
import win32gui
GetShellWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.GetShellWindow


def get_desktop():
    """Get the window of the icons, the desktop window contains this window"""
    shell_window = GetShellWindow()
    shell_dll_defview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(shell_window, 0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", "")
    if shell_dll_defview == 0:
        sys_listview_container = []
        try:
            win32gui.EnumWindows(_callback, sys_listview_container)
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            if e.winerror != 0:
                raise
        sys_listview = sys_listview_container[0]
    else:
        sys_listview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(shell_dll_defview, 0, "SysListView32", "FolderView")
    return sys_listview

def _callback(hwnd, extra):
    class_name = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    if class_name == "WorkerW":
        child = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "SHELLDLL_DefView", "")
        if child != 0:
            sys_listview = win32gui.FindWindowEx(child, 0, "SysListView32", "FolderView")
            extra.append(sys_listview)
            return False
    return True

def get_item_count(window):
    return win32gui.SendMessage(window, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT)

desktop = get_desktop()
get_item_count(desktop)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os

len(os.listdir('path/desktop'))
```

Comment: I actually want to get the positions of the icons and before that I need the number of icons. I have to use the same method for the positions anyway. Also I'm not sure that these methods will always return the same output - it's a good question. I primarily use this method because my sources suggested so (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop for example)

Comment: what actual code are you using? listdir returns everything on my desktop, I don't use so windows but I see people using   `commctrl.LVM_GETITEMCOUNT`?

Comment: Listdir doesn't help me to get the positions. And to get the positions I need to understand the method of win32gui and messages.

Comment: well your question was how to get the count so I did answer your question, editing and changing a question is not the way to go

Comment: My question was about using win32gui in python 2.7. Also I though my question was clear when I posted it, and I edited it when I realized it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: might be useful http://superuser.com/questions/625854/where-does-windows-store-icon-positions

Comment: Thanks for really trying to help! This: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop says that "Windows reads this information on LogIn and stores in on LogOut" which is not accurate enough for me.

Comment: can you add the exact code you use to try get the count including imports

Comment: See EDIT2, just added.

Comment: if you print `win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()` what does it return?

Comment: Something reasonable like 65552

Comment: OK the answer is in the second question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-do-i-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop `GetDesktopWindow()` returns is the actual desktop but you need  `FindWindowEx` to access the  Explorer desktop where the icons are stored

Comment: I understand what you say and I'm still trying to get it to work. No luck yet :(

Comment: Yay I finally got it! I essentially translated the code from the source above. I'll edit my question and add it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @EllaShar how did you get the locations of the icons?  I am trying to do the same thing now.

Comment: @feltersnach It's a code I wrote in 2014 so I don't remember much about it. Also I don't know a good site for uploading python code. I uploaded it here: https://trinket.io/python/9b0729bdd4 but it doesn't run there since trinket doesn't support all the builtin python modules. Copy the code and run it on your computer, it should work. Only tested on my windows 7 x64 so it probably won't work on windows 10. I got some helper materials I used. Tell me where to send them if you want.